# streamline passing user variable to controller laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using `$user = Auth::user();` in every method of my Projects controller.

I use it to get projects that belongs to user, and also pass to views.

How would I streamline that?

for example:

```
public function index()
    {
        $user     = Auth::user();
        $projects = $user->projects;
        return view('project.index', compact('user', 'projects'));
    }
```

I thought about using view composer but I still need $user inside controller for getting data...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access **$user** in every controller, you could have that injected by the **service container**. Laravel doesn't store user in the container, so you'd need to define your own service provider. Luckily, it's quite simple.

1. Implement the provider

   ```
   //app/Providers/CurrentUserServiceProvider.php
   <?php namespace App\Providers;

   use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

   class CurrentUserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
   {
     public function register() 
     {
       $this->app->bind(User::class, function ($app) {
         return Auth::user();  
       });
     }
   }
   ```
2. Register your provider

   ```
   //config/app.php
   'providers' => [
     //here go existing providers
     'App\Providers\CurrentUserServiceProvider'
   ]
   ```
3. Define **User** as a dependency in your controller action

   ```
   class MyController extends Controller {
     public function someAction(User $user) {
       echo $user->id;
     }
   }
   ```